# Call class method in the Array.map()

Tags: javascript

This is what I want to have:

```
function MyClass() {
   this.some = new Array();
   this.another = new Array();
}

MyClass.prototype.some_method = function(element) {
   // some work with this.some
}

MyClass.prototype.another_method = function() {
   this.another.map(function(el) {
     this.some_method(el);   // error code
   });
}
```

But I get error with it:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'empty_cell'
```

Is it possible to call MyClass methods in the anonymous function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `this` scope as a second parameter to the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.another_method = function() {
   this.another.map(function(el) {
     this.some_method(el);
   }, this); // added this
}
```